# Object modelling problem

Tags: c#, modeling

I have got class Car, and each class has list of extras (leather, abs, Folding mirrors etc...)

```
public Extra
{
public bool Paid {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Code {get;set;}
}
```

And now, better is:

```
class Car
{
public Extra Leather {get;set;}
public Extra FoldingMirrors {get;set;}
public Extra Abs {get;set;}
}
```

or better:

```
class Car
{
private List<Extra> _listOfExtras=new List<Extra>

public List<Extra> ListOfExtras
{
...
}
}
```

And the worst part:

My winforms application works offline and one per month is sending datas for me.

I must hold list Of available (foreach car user choose extras) extras in this application so better way I think is option one.

how hold this list of extras in my applications ? It connect with webservice only one time per month.

Comment: Can you fix some spelling issues and describe you last requirement about saving with more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list or dictionary (for easier access) of extras would be more flexible.

It would mean that as extras were added and/or removed from a car you wouldn't have to modify the `Car` class which you would have to do if each were added explicitly.

There are various ways to store the list locally. You could serialise to a file - either plain text or XML which would be better as you've got classes that do the serialisation for you, or you could hold it in a local database.

Comment: Ok, but how hold this list of extras in my applications ? It connect with webservice only one time per month

Comment: @phenevo - there are various ways to store the list locally. You could serialise to a file - either plain text or better XML, or you could hold it in a local database.

Answer (score 2):

Personally (seeing this is subjective), I would use an interface for Extra (eg IExtra). I would also go for the second 'option' of having a list/dictionary of extras contained in the Car class.

If needed, they can be exposed like in option 1, by just looking up the value in the list/dictionary.

Comment: Ok, but how hold this list of extras in my applications ? It connect with webservice only one time per month

Answer (score 1):

I would store it in a `Dictionary<string, Extra>`. You don't want the same extras showing up more than once... Or at least paying for them more than once :-)

Also, Extra should be an interface (or at the very least an abstract class)..

As for storage, you could serialize the Car class out to XML.